# Xamarin communication between devices, not using the internet

Tags: networking, client-server, xamarin

How would you go about if you would like to create something like:
You have let say 3 devices (can all be iOS or Android, a mix is not necessary)

- One of the devices would act as a master and the other two would connect to it and receive messages.
- They are on the same network but do not have internet (so no outside server like SignalR can be implemented looks like).
- When they receive messages (events) they act upon them.

I've been browsing the web for a while already but so far I've failed to find a promising solution.

Does anyone have experience with something like this?
Could I get some pointers on what to look for?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Net.Nsd.NsdManager/